# How to flag users

Tags: support, users, flags

I saw a user spamming Stack Overflow, how can I flag them for moderator attention other than posting here?

Comment: Latest question: "i think i need to ask few more questions to level my account zero..." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871087/bombs-away

Comment: That user's been deleted from the looks of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also flagged two posts and reported the user. I'm not sure there's much else you can do. It's either self-destruction or his account has been compromised (more likely, in my opinion). Either way it should be temporarily suspended.