# Area51: How do I flag a user? (And, Area51 policies therein?)

Tags: support, area-51, users, flags

I'm aware of the SOFU policy on "flagging users" (you don't, you flag their posts instead, and hope a keen moderator takes notice of the user's bad patterns).

**SOFU Policy on Flagging Users**

[Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)
[Function to flag users as spambots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29006/function-to-flag-users-as-spambots)
[How to flag users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32369/how-to-flag-users-closed)

Has the policy changed at all on Area51?

If so, how can I flag a user for constant badness?

Also, when I flag bad posts of this likeness, does it actually create any movement towards this user? (What I mean is, because Area51 is new and growing, when a post is flagged, what actually happens? Is there any process in place to halt these badly behaving users? )

Also, as an aside, who are these moderators on Area51, are they part of the StackExchange team? As a high rep user, I see no power tools aside from deletion votes & editing.

Comment: `const bool badness = true`

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55124/how-to-deal-with-disruptive-people-on-area51

Comment: Why wouldn't flagging a post of that user for moderator attention with a fitting message be enough on area51?